# Is there something like a "self-avoiding Markov chain" on a continuous space?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, markov-chains, random-walks, sampling

If stumbled accross [self-avoiding walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk)s. They seem to be deterministically generated, but from a quick google search term seem to be randomly generated variants.

However, as far as I can see they are only defined on a lattice (like $\mathbb Z^d$) (which is clearly not dense in $\mathbb R^d$). Now I wondered whether we can also stochastically generate a self-avoiding walk in continuous space, say (for simplicity) on $[0,1)^2$, such that the whole space is visited if the walk goes on forever (i.e. some kind of denseness is achieved).

As a further step, I would like to know whether this process can be constructed in a way such that it has the Markov property (but this seems to be pretty hard).

I'm thankful for any adivce and/or reference on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question is asked, the answer is "no": if a continuous curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to [0,1)^2$ is self-avoiding, i.e., injective, then the image $\gamma(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ is nowhere dense in $[0,1)^2$. Indeed, the images $\gamma([0,T])$ are compact, hence closed. Also, compactness implies the inverse map $\gamma^{-1}:\gamma([0,T])\to[0,T]$ is continuous, i.e., the image $\gamma([0,T])$ is homeomorphic to an interval. Hence, it cannot contain any balls, for if it did, removing a point from it would make the fundamental group non-trivial, while removing a point from an interval cannot do so.

Baire's theorem now implies that $\gamma(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})=\cup_{T\in\mathbb{N}}\gamma([0,T])$ is nowhere dense.

**Update:** one way to relax the self-avoidance property: we say that a curve is non-self-crossing if it belongs to the closure of the set of injective curves with respect to the metric
$$
d(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)=\inf_\sigma \sup_t|\gamma_1(\sigma(t))-\gamma_2(t)|.
$$
where the infimum is over all parametrizations $\sigma$. Such a curve may intersect its past trace, but then it bounces back on the same side it came from. The $SLE_\kappa$ curves are like that (but non-simple) for $\kappa>4$, and space filling for $\kappa\geq 8$. It is conjectured that self-avoiding walk on a lattice $\epsilon \mathbb{Z}^2$ (uniformly chosen from all walks staying in a domain $\Omega$ and with given endpoints) converges in the scaling limit $\epsilon\to 0$ to the $SLE_{8}$ process. See Duminil-Copin, H., Kozma, G., & Yadin, A. (2014). Supercritical self-avoiding walks are space-filling. In Annales de l'IHP Probabilités et statistiques (Vol. 50, No. 2, pp. 315-326).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We maybe need to strech the "denseness" notion a bit. What I thought about is something like a walk on $[0,1)^2\cap\varepsilon\mathbb Z^2$ (but what I'm searching for would be someting "more random" than a regular grid). As $\varepsilon\to0+$, this is still "dense".

Answer (score 1):

In dimension 2, we have the Schramm and Loewner evolutions, very nice processes which are invariant by conformal maps (up to time-changes).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-39982-7_2

https://www.studocu.com/en-gb/document/the-chancellor-masters-and-scholars-of-the-university-of-cambridge/schramm-loewner-evolutions/lecture-notes-schramm-loewner-evolutions-complete/726002

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, in your references there is a lot of theory involved which I'm not familiar with and I would need to dive into. Could you shortly explain how these evolutions could be used to reach my goal? Can we generate such an evolution (on $[0,1)^2$) numerically?

Comment: Look at the wikipedia page added in the references.

Comment: I already looked at the wikipedia page and I thinnk it is rather confusing. I don't even understand the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution#Example). "Loewner's equation" is a differential equation relating functions $f,g,\zeta$. Why is $\zeta$ suddenly a Brownian motion? Where does stochastic come into the game at all?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, Loewner evolution is a (rather convoluted) method to encode a planar curve (say in the upper half-plane) by a real-valued "driving function" $\zeta(t)$, $t\geq 0$. The example is for the case $\zeta(t)\equiv 0$, which encodes the vertical straight line ray.  If you take $\zeta$ to be a random function, then the curve will also be random.

Comment: @Kostya_I Did I understand this correctly: Let $(\xi_t)_{t\ge0}$ denote a "driving function" (for example, $\xi_t=\sqrt\kappa B_t$ for some Brownian motion $B$) and $(g_t)_{t\ge0}$ denote the solution of $$g_t(z)=z+\int_0^t\frac2{g_s(z)-\xi_s}\:{\rm d}s.$$ Then the curve we are actually considering is $\gamma_t:=g_t^{-1}(\xi_t)$. Now, there are two issues: (a) $\gamma_t$ moves in $\mathbb H:=\{z\in\mathbb C:\Re(z)>0\}$, but I need a cruve in $[0,1)^2$. How do I fix that? (b) Everything can be easily obtained numerically, but how should I numerically compute the inverse $γ_t=g_t^{-1}(\xi_t)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d the SLE process in $(0,1)^2$ is the image of the process in $\mathbb{H}$ under a conformal map. (Alternatively, you can conformally transplant the Lowener ODE into $(0,1)^{2}$ by a conformal map and solve the resulting equation) As for the second question, look up numerical simulations of SLE, people have done it and it's not trivial.

Comment: @Kostya_I If $\gamma_t$ is the curve in $\mathbb H$, how do we obtain the curve in $(0,1)^2$ from that? How is the conformal map defined you are talking about? If you got a reference for me, that would already been really helpful.

Comment: To get a conformal bijection between the half upper plane and a square, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I was able to implement the evolution on $\mathbb H$, but I really got some trouble to even understand the definition of the conformal map to $(0,1)^2$ given in the Wikipedia article. Please take a look at the question I've asked for that: https://mathoverflow.net/q/436590/91890.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Here is a plot of my implementation of the SLE for $\kappa=8$, $10.000$ points and up to time $t=1$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orBbG.png (the time steps are uniform; I know that it is better to adapteively refine depending on the sampled path of the Brownian motion, but that's not the point in the sequel). Now, I've applied a conformal map from $\mathbb H$ to $[0,1]^2$ and obtained https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4gTL.png. As you can see, everything seems to get concentraited on the right (and this gets even worse for larger $t$).

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan So, as long as I didn't made any mistake in my conformal map to $[0,1]^2$, this seems to be bad for my purposes. What I actually wanted to obtain is a space-filling curve on $[0,1]^2$. What do you think?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I am not a specialist on this topic. According to Kostya_I, $SLE_\kappa$ is space filling as soon as $\kappa \ge 8$. This may be more visible for larger values of $\kappa$. You can find other simulations there https://www.math.arizona.edu/~tgk/sle/

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Yes, it should be space-filling. But as you can see the map to $[0,1]^2$ gives a poor result (hopefully I did not make any mistake in the implementation, but I don't see where it should be)

Comment: I do not know. Compare your simulations with T Kennedy's ones and try larger values of $\kappa$. I have no other idea on this question.