# Numerically compute the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping to the square

Tags: numerical-integration, conformal-maps, elliptic-integrals

I want to map the upper-half plane $$\mathbb H:=\{z\in\mathbb C:\Im(z)>0\}$$ to $[0,1)^2$ by a conformal map. If I got this right, then such a mapping is given by the [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping#Square) to the square.

Now, I need to implement this mapping in a C++ program and hence I guess I need to numerically compute the integrat in the definition of the mapping. But how do we need to do this? What kind of integral is this at all?

According to the wikipedia article, the mapping is given by

$$z\mapsto\int^z\frac{{\rm d}w}{\sqrt{w(1-w^2)}}=\sqrt 2F(\sqrt{z+1};\sqrt 2/2)\tag1.$$ I guess this integral is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) (which I never heard about before). But I don't get the parameters. From the Wikipedia article about the elliptic integral, shouldn't the first parameter be a real numbers (instead of the complex number $\sqrt{z+1}$)?

*Remark*: the C++ standard contains the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind, which we might need to use: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/special_functions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thank you for your comment. What exactly do I need to look up? Could you refer me to an explicit reference? I've seen that a similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/266269/47771) was asked on MSE, but shouldn't I need a map which maps $-\infty$ to $(0, 0)$, $\infty$ to $(0, 1)$ and $\infty+{\rm i}\infty$ to $(1,1)$ (if that makes sense)?

Comment: You have to look at the Abramowitz and Stegun book, https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~aps/research/projects/as/resources/AandS-a4-v1-2.pdf section 18.14, page 658.

Comment: I am sorry, this is is called the "Lemniscatic case", $g_2=1,g_3=0$. (Wikipedia has completely confused terminology!)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thank you for the link. Unfortunately, it is quite hard to read the material for me. How would I actually implement this? The C++ tandard already contains a function to compute incomplete elliptic integrals of the first kind, but I don't get the parameterization for $F$ which is used there (and the result is a double; hence not a complex number).

Comment: I can't help with the numeric stuff and I don't remember how elliptic $F$ works, but if it's of any use, I can show the (fairly short) [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) code I used to compute [this image](http://www.madore.org/~david/images/conformal-map-square.png) ([larger version as PDF](http://www.madore.org/~david/images/conformal-map-square.pdf)) some years ago. Maybe you can use it, say, as a check against another implementation or something.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thank you for your comment. It would be really helpful if we could rewrite the integral in terms of elliptic integrals with real limits. Is that possible?

Comment: BTW; i can‘t find a reference for the formula for $f$, which is from the Wikipedia article of the Schwarz-Christoffel transformation, but it differs from all other formulas of maps onto rectangles which I found in textbooks.

Comment: @0xbadf00d [Here's my code](https://gist.github.com/Gro-Tsen/fa1f2c6ee425a87618763afe897f448e#file-square-conformal-map-sage) (I put analogous code for an ellipse instead of a square as well, so make sure you look at the right one: you want the function `phi` from `square-conformal-map.sage`, it's only a few lines long). Again, there are many different conventions for parameters of elliptic integrals, I completely forgot how they work so I can't say, but this should at least help you check numerically.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thanks for sharing! According to your code comments, the function phi maps the unit disk (hence not the upper-half plane) to the square $[-1,1]^2$. But I need a map from the upper-half plane to $[0,1]^2$. Didn't thought that would be such a hard problem. My main problem is that I don't really understand why $(1)$ works at all (since I can't find a reference for that) and how we can rewrite $(1)$ as real and imaginary parts (which seems to be possible according to cs.bham.ac.uk/~aps/research/projects, 17.4.11.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The upper-half-plane is mapped conformally to the unit disk by $z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ (it's a standard fact that any disk in the Riemann sphere are mapped to any other by a Möbius transformation, and the upper-half-plane is a disk). The square $[-1,1]+i[-1,1]$ is of course mapped to $[0,1]+i[0,1]$ by $z\mapsto (z+1+i)/2$, so these are trivial problems: you can just compose all that. How to compute the elliptic integral and why it works, however, is a more serious question, but I don't remember this stuff.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Wait a second. If we got a conformal map from $\mathbb H$ to the unit disk and a conformal map from the unit disk to $[0,1]^2$, then the composition should be a confomal map from $\mathbb $ to $[0,1]^2$, right? But (a) in which way does it differ from $(1)$ and (b) in your code, is `t` a complex number and hence the subsequent invocation of `elliptic_f` one with a complex argument?

Comment: Yes, everything is complex and `elliptic_f` is invoked with a complex argument. It's a complex function, despite what the C++ standard is trying to make you believe. I think maybe the question you want to ask is “is there some way I can compute complex values of incomplete elliptic integrals given an implementation that will compute their real values”, which is a valid question, and to which I don't have an answer. But if all else fails you can probably look at the code of one of the many pieces of code that *do* implement complex values (like Sage's, which probably uses Maxima).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Why does $(1)$ work at all? Look at [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%282%29*EllipticF%5Bsqrt%28sin%280%29%2B1%29%2Csqrt%282%29%2F2%5D). Which points $z\in\mathbb H$ are mapped to $0$, $1$, $1+{\rm i}$ and ${\rm i}$, respectively? (Or does the map from wikipedia article *not* map $[0,1]^2$, but some other square?)

Comment: Sadly, there are many different conventions on how to express the parameters to elliptic functions, Wolfram Alpha and Wikipedia may not use the same, and I don't remember how they are related. Which is why I suggested Sage code which I know works, and which you can try. It's not supposed to be another formula, just an implementation that I know works of what you're trying to do. (But to be extra clear, there's no way around computing `elliptic_f` in some form: the conformal mapping is essentially unique, so if that's what you need, that's what you need.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Sorry, I never heard about "sage" before. Do you mean their implementation of `elliptic_f`? Where can I find it? ... Unfortunately, this is all very unsatisfactory. All I want to do is map $\mathbb H$ to $[0,1]^2$ in a computer program. I'm willing to invest time into this, but I wasn't able to find a *good* reference which validates that $(1)$ is actually the right map and which deals with the numerical implementation of this (which should be something many people need; not only in mathalb, etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141336/discussion-between-gro-tsen-and-0xbadf00d).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Once again responded in the chat